# Not support large file content using tinyMCE editor

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, richfaces, tinymce

I read the file (**File Size is more than 2.5Mb**) and display the content into textarea using **tinyMCE**.

Script Error occur during loading time into textarea.
The error is

```
A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. 
You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost:8080/tiny-rich-editor/faces/tinyEditor-orginal/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1
```

This error after i use the following code in tinyMCE

```
ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
                // Replaces all \n characters with <br> tag
                o.content = o.content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
            });
```

The above code for show the content as line by line. If not use the above code, then textarea show all the content as not original format. like line by line.

Help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can't be called "script error", because there were no errors there. Instead the browser wasn't sure whether the long waiting time was intentional -- which **IS** this case. If you wait some more time probably the tinyMCE will still display the result.

ThiefMaster's right: don't try to load huge file into Javascript WYSIWYG editor. The Javascript is always run in interpreted mode, and once the whole text is loaded, the parsing and formatting begin. It's just too costly to process 2.5MB text using Javascript running on your browser.

Comment: How much maximum filesize allowed by tinyMCE?

Comment: Technically it's only limited by the string size Javascript capable of handling, and the size of memory on your browser. On the other hand, for practical purpose we need to test the user experience when loading such large text. Different workstation with different memory size, number or running processes, operating systems, browsers may produce different experiences.

Comment: A better solution would be to break down the text into sections, displaying summary and put edit button by those sections.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: Don't load huge files into a JavaScript-based WYSIWYG editor (or even into a plain textarea). It takes very long and thus the user is asked if he wants to interrupt the script.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that everything you add into your tinymce editor instance needs to be verified by the browser.
Inserting i.e. more than 200-300 Paragraphs into your editor will result in highly increased computation time (consumed by the broweser). 2,5 MB filesize does not sound that much, but keep in mind that this is much text.

You might want to think about spliting your huge file into many smaller chunks in order to make them editable using a textarea or a tinymce editor.

Comment: I want to load file, size is 1.4MB using tinyMCE. Is possible??

Comment: 1,4 MB for a text file is still very much (processing using js)

Comment: I tried to load 1.4 mb size. And content.replace method. The browser can't load the script. So, i tried to another way,In back end i read whole file content, then content=content.replaceAll("\n","<br>). But no reflection in my textarea.

Answer (score 1):

**@EswaraMoorthyNEC** 
Hi,
Why you use tinyMCE...you can load the file content intonormal text area

Comment: I want do some operation like search the word,print,save etc..in textarea content.

Comment: @Eswar: I check it your code..I load the file. Script error not occur for me.

Comment: editor allowed for normal file(small size) .but When i load more than 2MB size, that time the browser show alert message.

Comment: I think, the editor does not support when you reformat the textarea contnet.

Comment: Ya. I use the following line o.content = o.content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'); Then the browser show the alert message like warning message.
But i need to show the textarea content as line by line(like file original content)

Comment: couln'd you solve that issue by making the tinymce editor instance wide enough?

Comment: I did manually print,save operation in textarea content without using. I want to searching process. so i using tinyMCE. Without using tinyMCE, is possible to search the word in inside of textarea. give me a refernce, links